# Add embedded base64 image to java email

Tags: java, email, playframework, base64

I am using `com.typesafe.plugin.MailerAPI` to send emails.
i need to add a base64 image in the email.

i added it to the body:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src=data:image/png;base64,iV****/>
```

but it does not show in the email.
any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Try with quotes: `<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iV****" />`. What is the result in the source of the email?

Comment: i tried the qutoes same thing. in the email it appears an empty image with aly text only

Comment: Look at the **source** of the email.

Comment: shows this only <img alt="Embedded Image">

Comment: You can try this [example from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Base64 images don't work with all email clients. You can use attachments with cid's (content id's).